# Copying .svn File?

Tags: c#, svn, copy

I'm trying to automate some stuff in SVN, and part of that is copying a .svn file (the one that contains where a directory should update their files from) to a local drive.

I'm using the following code:

```
File.Copy(@"X:\SVN\.svn", @"C:\SVN\.svn, true");
```

And I get the following error:

```
Access to the path 'X:\SVN\.svn' is denied
```

Am I just not allowed to move these types of files around?  I know by default they are hidden, so maybe that's what's going on.  Or is there a way in C#, I can just create a new .svn file so I don't have to bother with permissions and the like?

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean the `.svn` *directory*?

Comment: Yes, I thought it was a file, I was cornfused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last time I checked, `.svn` was a directory. You probably can't copy a directory with File.Copy, or the directory is in use (sharing lock).

Have a look at ProcessExplorer's find function (in Sysinternal Suite) to find out which process uses it (perhaps TortoiseSVN?)

Perhaps schedule your replication using [Rich Copy](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/d/0/fd05def7-68a1-4f71-8546-25c359cc0842/HoffmanUtilitySpotlight2009_04.exe) which is a RoboCopy clone from Microsoft that will copy permissions, incremental update etc.

Comment: and usually even if you have tortoise closed there is a tortoise cache that stays running that keeps handles so that tortoise can show status faster.

Comment: Ahh, of course, so I simply can copy all of the files inside of .svn?  but then, how to I make my new .svn directory have the same properties as the old one (so it can be recognized by SVN and hidden)?

Comment: I would look at XCOPY, RoboCopy or [RichCopy from microsoft](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/d/0/fd05def7-68a1-4f71-8546-25c359cc0842/HoffmanUtilitySpotlight2009_04.exe)

Answer (score 1):

Typically this is because you have tortoise running, and the tortoise cache has the file locked. If you shut it down in task manager you can do whatever you'd like with hit.

That said, what is the purpose of copying it? Are you cloning the project?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows and using TortoiseSVN, then the .svn is actually a directory so you can't use File.Copy on it.

Comment: .svn is always actually a directory, whether you use Tortoise or not

Comment: @sehe - It's more of an implementation detail and isn't really required to be a directory. But probably is in most cases.

Comment: I'm interested in the counter example. I know you can configure TortoiseSVN to use a different name (_svn) e.g. to avoid conflicts with (older) IIS deployments

Comment: @sehe - I'm not saying there is any SVN client out there that uses a single file, but it could be done. I'm only familiar with TortoiseSVN, which uses a directory. There are other SVN clients that could use a single file for simplicity.